# R in loop processing error (linear regression)

Tags: r

I want to loop through linear regression processing in R language.
The following code returns an error.

```
for ( i in 1:34) {
for( j in 15:51)
y.1 <- y[i : j]
x.1 <- 1:15
y.lm <- lm(y.1 ~ x.1)
alpha[i] <- unname(y.lm$coefficients[2])
}
```

y is time series data with 51 elements.
The error contents are

```
The length of variable (based on 'x.1') is different
```

help me.

Comment: as the error says, `x.1` is always of length 15.  while y.1 changes.  You can check by `print(length(y.1))` within the for loop

Comment: It would be useful if a sample of data like your original is provided in order to solve your proble. You might try to simulate random data with such as `x = 1:100` and `y = rnorn(100,0,1)` or use one of the example data set pre-loaded in R such as `load(iris)` or `load(mtcars)`. Know the structure of your data will help us to structure the answer.

Comment: Also, nesting a loop like this will lead to redundant results. You will loop through every `15:51` of `j` for every `1:34` of `i`, which means for example you compute the `lm` for both of `y[15:16]` and `y[16:15]`.